# Wrap an image into a parent

Tags: javascript, html

Before-hand I apologize for any doublets, I've searched a little but haven't found a script that fits my needs. (BTW: Javascript isn't my strong side)

What I need, is a script that wraps up every image inside the div class "post" with the div class "parent".

What I have is the following:

```
<div class="post">
<img src="aSimpleImage.png">
</div>
```

**What I want the outcome to be:**

```
<div class="post">
<div class="parent"><img src="aSimpleImage.png"></div>
</div>
```

I want the script to be pure, vanilla Javascript, no jQuery or extra external http requests for script languages.  I tried:

```
var parent = element.parentNode; 
var wrapper = document.createElement('.parent'); // set the wrapper as child (instead of the element) 
parent.replaceChild(img, .parent); // set element as child of wrapper  
wrapper.appendChild(element);
```

EDIT:
Found this snippet

```
// create the container div
var dv = document.createElement('div');
// get all divs
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
// get the body element
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

// apply class to container div
dv.setAttribute('class', 'container');

// find out all those divs having class C
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
{
   if (divs[i].getAttribute('class') === 'C')
   {
      // put the divs having class C inside container div
      dv.appendChild(divs[i]);
   }
}

// finally append the container div to body
body.appendChild(dv);
```

Would someone be kind an elaborate this into what I'm requesting?

Comment: Did you try anything?  Post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
function imgWrap(parent) {
    if (!parent || parent.nodeType !== 1) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var images = parent.getElementsByTagName('img'),
            newDiv = document.createElement('div'),
            tmp;
        newDiv.className = 'parent';
        for (var i = 0, len = images.length; i < len; i++) {
            tmp = newDiv.cloneNode(true);
            parent.insertBefore(tmp, images[i])
            tmp.appendChild(images[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zSZQ4/).